# Dynamic Navigation drawer item in Navigation component architecture Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I an unable to figure out any possible solution to **load drawer items dynamically** i.e hide and show particular items as required in **Navigation component Architecture** Android. Reason being Navigation component architecture forces us to manually inflate drawer by adding items in xml and then add it through code.

**Please help if anyone has any idea to do it dynamically like fetching the items from API and populating them.**

*Note:- Those who don't have idea please do not underrate it or ask for un-necessary code snippet as this fact is a descriptive one and not any code issue.*

Comment: use RecyclerView in Navigation Drawer, it will work

Comment: use `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to inflate menu items dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can build your menu items dynamically.

Fist step - find your navigation view in your Activity

```
private lateinit var navView: NavigationView
...
navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
```

Second step - inflate navigation view with items like this

```
        pages.forEach { page ->
            navView.menu.add(0, page.navId, 0, page.name)
                .apply {
                    setNavItemIcon(this, page.faIcon, page.customIcon)
                    isCheckable = true
                }
        }

        navView.menu.setGroupCheckable(0, true, true)
```

where pages - list of navigation item models, fetched from db (in your case API) and 'page' is the model of the menu item.

Third step - use setNavigationItemSelectedListener for handling clicks

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    onMenuItemSelected(it, pages)
}
```

Also you maybe you'll need to use navView.menu.clear() to clear menu and inflate it again.